# Can CompanySettings be retrieved using the Tooling API?

Tags: tooling-api

The CompanySettings object can be retrieved using the Metadata API. However it requires using SOAP and zip files.

Is there a way to retrieve it using the, much simpler, Tooling API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. I checked the Tooling APi, object list and unable to find reference of this object. So I think your only option is Metadata API.

[Reference : Tooling API object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm)